# Curl to fetch multiple JSON objects

Tags: python, json, curl, sed

I have to call a service to fetch some data from it. I use curl for it

**Curl Command**

```
< /example/data/sample.dat xargs -P10 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -X GET -L  > /example/json/data.json
```

I have my application token which I use here.

The file sample.dat looks like this

```
"http://xxx/marketing/insights/v1/info?id=0553153617,B003W0CI6Y,B000R08E7Y,B001O2SAAU,B00B1MP3MG,B00QRHJBPU,B00007B4DC,0852597088,B0000003H4,1937715213&fields=product.title,product.url,&fieldgroups=default"
"http://xxx/marketing/insights/v1/info?id=0553153617,B003W0CI6Y,B000R08E7Y,B001O2SAAU,B00B1MP3MG,B00QRHJBPU,B00007B4DC,0852597088,B0000003H4,1937715213&fields=product.title,product.url,&fieldgroups=default"
"http://xxx/marketing/insights/v1/info?id=0746029853,1613210035,B004SI9OKW,1572841451,B00FC1BQUA,3170218085,B009QJYBVK,B0181P5E42,B01J8JRZ92,0961268611&fields=product.title,product.url,&fieldgroups=default"
"http://xxx/marketing/insights/v1/info?id=1402206836,B006FQQMZA,1624386903,B001ANZW0O,0872200450,B0035LCSCO,B00JRQ7T5W,1401951341,B00PKSCDRU,B00PKR4UW2&fields=product.title,product.url,&fieldgroups=default"
```

So as you see I make parallel calls with 10 ids to the service.

The output that I receive is 3 JSON objects in the file `/example/json/data.json`.

Example:

```
{.....}{...}{...}
```

Now when I have to parse it using python, it fails saying invalid json. Thats correct because the file does not represent a standard JSON array

So using sed I tried to change it to

```
[{.....},{...},{...}]
```

Now this looks like JSON and can be parsed. This logic worked fine for small data but with larger data, I think my sed was not able to put the `,` at the right place inside JSON and hence it resulted in incorrect file. As a result JSON parser in python is failing.

Now I was thinking if I can have the individual JSON objects on each line
like

```
{...}
{...}
{...}
```

That way I can read the file line by line.

Can someone help with how I can change the curl to output individual jsons on each line like

```
{...}
{...}
{...}
```

Comment: That worked for few but not all cases. Somewhere in the middle it is misbehaving

Comment: Why don't you write them to separate JSON files instead of all going to the same file?

Comment: Can you suggest how do I tweak my curl statement here?

Comment: Does your input file really have quotes around the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write each result to a different JSON file.

```
i=0
while read url; do
    curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -X GET -L > data.$i.json
    i=$((i+1))
done < sample.dat
```

Or you could write to a single file in the loop, inserting the comma separators between the elements.

```
i=0
while read url; do
    if [[ i -eq 0 ]]
        then echo '['
        else echo ','
    fi
    curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -X GET -L 
    i=$((i+1))
done < sample.dat > data.json
echo ']' >> data.json
```